# How to add an object from a class to an instantiated window?

Tags: c#, wpf, instances

I've got a fairly simple C# / WPF question. My skills in C# / WPF are not that good so I do apologize if the answer is already out there but I wasn't smart enough to see it.

I've got a main window which I instantiated from my App.xaml.cs

```
internal static MainWindow mw;
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //investwindow = new Invest();
                mw = new MainWindow();
                mw.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

My mainwindow class contains a bunch of buttons which instantiate other windows / classes, for example:

```
private void btnInvest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            investwindow = new Invest();
            investwindow.Show();
        }
```

On this investwindow in XAML I have a grid called "InvestSP".
Upon running the code for investwindow, I run a class called "StockItem", which takes a whole bunch of inputs and writes them into a groupbox and a few textboxes, and places them into the stackpanel. I won't copy the whole code of the StockItem class, but the last part is the one generating the errors when I try to add the groupbox into the stackpanel:

```
try
            {
                App.mw.investwindow.InvestSP.Children.Add(GroupB);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
```

Error message says System.NullReferenceException: Object Reference not set to an Instance of an Object.

I've tried many things, some don't help, some make it worse. I know it's due to my lack of understanding, but please be patient with me, I am just trying my best.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you need more information or code just let me know.

With gratitude!

Wouter

Comment: You're trying to dereference something `null` (you generally get this error if you say `a.b` and `a` is `null`). Put a breakpoint on that line and see what is `null`.

Comment: In your invest_Click (assuming this is in your MainWindow code), what is investwindow? Is this a public variable in the MainWindow clasS?

Comment: You are right, I did find something on a particular object completely unrelated to what I thought was the issue. I got it resolved thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you do not set App.mw.investwindow object. You can find the null object by debugging to make sure. What I suggest is as follows:

You can create a static collection in your `App.xaml.cs` that holds reference to any data object that you will need in your windows.

```
public static ObservableCollection<GroupB> GroupBs {get; set;} // in App.xaml.cs
```

Set ItemsSource of your InvestSP grid to this collection.

When you would like to add something to your `InvestSP` grid from another window just add your object into this collection:

```
App.GroupBs.Add(GroupB);
```

You will see that your grid is updated.